# NGINX: How to capture / log IP visiting a given location on a text file

Tags: nginx, ip

I would like to be able to log/capture the IPs of visitors to a given location on my sites.
The idea is to have 2 conf files to be used for whitelisting or blacklisting.

- The bad guys could be listed automatically and blocked by the server
- The admins could visit a secret address to have their IP whitelisted before they access the admin area.

The problem is that I can't find how to have nginx write IPs in my conf files.

Example:

```
location ~* ^/(trustme)/?$
    add "allow X.X.X.X;" to /etc/nginx/conf.d/trusted-ips.conf;
}

location ~* ^/(admin|wp-admin|control)/?$
    add "deny Y.Y.Y.Y;" to /etc/nginx/conf.d/blacklisted_ips.conf;
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding you want to add the ip which are trusted in one file and then allow them on specific location and ip which are suspicious you want to move them to other file and then put some limitation on those ips?

If i understand correctly you can awk ip of page 1

```
awk '$7 ~ /^\/page1?/ {print $1}' /path/to/access.log | sort -u > result.txt
```

and then awk the ip on page2 or admin using same command and store them on other location.

Comment: Thanks Amrit,
So you would use the logs to pickup the addresses?

On my Centos8 that would be for example:

sudo awk '/vendor/ {print $11}' /var/log/nginx/site-error_log | tr -d , | sort -u >> /etc/nginx/conf.d/blacklisted_ips.conf    -   

The issue is that it won't be in realtime right?
I would need to run the command on cron, isn't it?

Thanks

Comment: you can run the cron every minute or if you want real time you can dump it in different directory asynchronously and run the script on access time change which will be very close to real time.Otherwise use the dynamic blacklisting method mentioned in https://www.nginx.com/blog/dynamic-ip-denylisting-with-nginx-plus-and-fail2ban/

Comment: Thanks a lot Amrit. Could you precise what you mean by "Drop in different directory asynchronously"? I am hesitant in using the logs because I have 17 sites with different pools and logs for each. I would need to analyse the entire growing log files every minutes then compare the IPs with existing IPs in the list to only add the new ones? Even if I rotate the logs every week and keep only 50 or 100 IPs in the list that is going to add significant work to my already busy server, isn't it? That is why I was thinking about using NGINX directly originally. Thanks a lot.

Comment: dumping access to achieve will be overkill. The only thing you can do is to cron after every 5 mins the awk command to get list of ip for each website and amend the whitelist and blacklist. The other best way to do is to rerun iptables everytime with new set of ip to block anything from them instead of using it on nginx layer.